# "Улетает" элемент при уменьшении сайта

Tags: responsive, mobile-web, html, вёрстка, css

Есть сайт (мобильная версия) http://smartwallapp.zz.mu/, дело в том что при уменьшении сайта, треугольник справа улетает, а левый нет, почему так и как фиксить?

Answer (score 3):

"Улетает" потому что у него задано свойство position: relative и фиксированое значение left: 308px. При уменьшении экрана он никуда не двигается. Чтобы избежать этого, есть несколько способом:

- Указать .msg-wrap position: relative, а .arrow-right position: absolute и нужный top и right
- Использовать псевдоэлементы :before или :after. В случае с право стрелочкой нужен :after.

Comment: не совсем понял как использовать в данном случае :after

Comment: На эту тему куча статей, например: [CSS Quick Tip: CSS Arrows and Shapes Without Markup](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/)

Comment: странно, сделал все как написано, все равно улетает, взгляни http://smartwallapp.zz.mu/